# How to get rebar's material in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm new to Revit API and I can use "GetMaterialIds(false)" to get the materials of an element, but it seems doesn't work for rebar. But I found the "GetMaterialIds()" method in the "Rebar" class in RevitAPIDocs. So, what should I do to find the material for the rebar element? Thank you!

Comment: I find some methods from official help. https://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-FD067FA5-623D-474B-98FB-686C096F0165 I have tried to find the material through "Rebar.Parameters", but there is no parameter with "ParameterType.Material"; I also tried to find through "Rebar.Category", but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the Revit API!

Please start by working through the [getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2) and installing [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup). With that knowledge and toolset, you will be able to easily answer this very basic question yourself, and probably many others that will soon come up as well.

Still, for the sake of completeness, to answer your question directly: you can obtain a list of all materials contributing to a BIM element by calling its [`GetMaterialIds` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/6011352e-151b-b8ac-14cc-45970f2fe5ad.htm)

Comment: Thanks very much, Jeremy! I found the material of rebars through RevitLoopup! Thanks a lot! It's a very useful tool!

Comment: Very glad to hear it helped. Thank you for your appreciation. Please mark my answer as useful, then. Can you also share your resulting solution code snippet for others to see? Thank you!